# update Programtically created Product

Tags: magento-1.9, product, module, controllers, session

We have 2 buttons in Product view page, after we click on 1st button, we creating Product Programtaically.

once click on 2nd button [ after entering email, password] we are assigning that product to that customer.

Here issue is saving "customer id"  value in Attribute [ attribute id : custom_uid ] is not working.

as we create the product after click on 1st button, is there any way to update the same product on click 2nd button

```
protected function _createProduct($type, $doSave = true, $originalProduct, $newImagePath = "")
    {

        Mage::register('isSecureArea', true);
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');

        $result = array(
            'success' => false
        );

        $login = "";
        $productId = "";
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $login = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');
            $productId = $this->getRequest()->getPost('product_id');
        }

        try {
            if (isset($login) && (is_array($login) && !empty($login)) || ($login != "")) {
                $designId = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getData('mydesign_id');
                $session->login($login['username'], $login['password']);
                $result['redirect'] = $this->_getRefererUrl() ? $this->_getRefererUrl() : Mage::getUrl('customer/account', array(
                    '_secure' => true
                ));
                $result['success'] = true;
                $customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
                $model = Mage::getModel('example/mydesign')->load($designId);
                if ($model->getId()) {
                    $model->setData('customer_id',$customerId);
                    $model->save();
                }

                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->unsetData('mydesign_id');
                $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
                return $this;
            } else {
                $customerId = "";
            }        

            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

            $product->setName($originalProduct->getName());

            $customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId(); 
            $product->setCustomUid($customerId);   // fetching cutomer id

            if ($doSave) {              
            }
            $product->save();

            $fav1_id = '';
            $data = array(
                'title' => $fav1_id,
                'product_id' => $product->getId(),
                'customer_id' => $customerId

            );
            //echo '<pre/>';
            $model = Mage::getModel('example/mydesign')->setData($data);
            try {
                $fav1_id = $model->save()->getId();
                if (!$customerId) {
                    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setData('mydesign_id', $fav1_id);
                }

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
            // To save

            return $product;           

        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            switch ($e->getCode()) {
                case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_NOT_CONFIRMED:
                    $message = Mage::helper('customer')->__('This account');
                    break;             
                default:
                    $message = $e->getMessage();
            }
            $result['error'] = $message;
            $session->setUsername($login['username']);

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $result = "ERROR :" . $e->getMessage();

        }

        Mage::unregister('isSecureArea');
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));

    }
```

Comment: A product has a few other important attributes such as store_id, attribute_set_id, type_id, sku, weight, tax_class_id, stock_data, etc., which need to be defined before `$product->save();`. Suggest you google _magento creating product programmatically_ to learn how to do it properly.

Comment: @kiatng We included all those details before  `$product->save();` , but our requirement is to update the `already created product` , can you please help for this....

Comment: For existing product, you need to load the model first before updating its attributes and saving. There are a few ways to load a product, again, you can google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `_createProduct` function

before `$product->save();`

add below line

```
$product->setStore(0);
```

Comment: I updated your code, but now after entering email id & pw and click on 2nd button, i cant able to login to the site.....

Comment: @vickeycolors please check updated answer

Comment: updated, now i can able to login as before, but `saving "customer id" value in Attribute` is still not working, can you please do something.....

Comment: product is created or not ??

Comment: product is created fine, but i need to save the `customer id value` in one of the  attribute.....

Comment: echo $login in this code ` if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $login = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');
            $productId = $this->getRequest()->getPost('product_id');
        }`

Comment: we are using this code to fetch customer id `$customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId(); $product->setCustomUid($customerId);` , its  working fine if we create product with registered users, but not working for guest.....

Comment: in guest user you dont have customer id

Comment: yes, when guest user click on `button1` &  product will create in backend. at that time, there will be no customer id , thats fine, but after we click on 2nd button `guest will become customer` we need to pass that customer id in that product.....

Comment: `echo $login;` didt gave any result...... we are using this code for fetching customer id : `$customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId(); $product->setCustomUid($customerId); `

Answer (score 0):

There are two major ways to load a product, `load()` and `loadByAttribute`. Because a product can be a member of more than one store, which we can set different attributes' values for, we need to specify which store we want for the update. In your case, since the product is associated with a customer, we can get the *store_id* from it.

```
 $storeId = $customer->getStoreId();    
 $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->setStoreId($storeId);
 // if you know the product ID
 $product->load($productId);
 // if you know the sku
 $product->loadByAttribute($sku, 'sku');
 // you can load by another attribute, if the name of the product is unique
 $product->loadByAttribute($name, 'name');
```

Comment: Thanks , may i use this code in same function as i was using to create product : `protected function _createProduct` or is i need to include in different function ?

Comment: i tried in same function, but i got : `Fatal error : call to member function getStoreId() on a non object` , please check [full code](https://pastebin.com/173r45w1)

Comment: Try define `$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()` before accessing it.

Comment: updated, can you please check error : http://prnt.sc/f3jrqn